# Replace nested loop with Java streams

Tags: java

how can I replace the following code with Streams?

```
 Annotation[][] annotations = context.getMethod().getParameterAnnotations();
        Object[] parameterValues = context.getParameters();
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < annotations.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < annotations[i].length; j++) {
                if (annotations[i][j] instanceof CacheKey && parameterValues[i] != null) {
                    stringBuilder.append(parameterValues[i]);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

I can easily use flatmap to get data from the first array of array, but I have no idea how to get the position to fetch the right value from parameterValues[i].

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could zip `annotations` with `paremeterValues` using [some known method](https://www.baeldung.com/java-collections-zip), but you should also ask yourself "is this gonna be more readable and better that it already is?". Short answer - no.

You compare `parameterValues[i] != null` in the inner loop when you can actually extract it level higher (Is this even needed? Ain't parameters not null by default?). You could also replace the inner loop with for-each, or even better refactor to simple `matchAny()` on stream or (the best) use `getAnnotation()`. Check also if you can get annotations directly from Parameter, so that it would boil down to a simple:

```java
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (var param : context.getParameters()) {
    if (param != null // is it needed ?
        && param.getAnnotation(CacheKey::class) != null)
        sb.append(param);
}
```